# Cannot serialize field with nil value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, memcached

I have two applications accessing one cache and both are storing and reading data from it. These apps have are different Rails versions (one is 3.2 and other is 3.0).

Model that I am storing in cache has field image_url that I am serializing in Array

```
 serialize :image_urls, Array
```

Here is the problem... I store the instance in the cache from App3.0(Rails version 3.0) and the value of that instance in the cache for image_urls is nil (rather than []). Once I try to load and access the instance from App3.2 I get the following error:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

Note: I cannot upgrade Rails version of App3.0